# Froala editor hide image edit option in Angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6, froala

i use the Froala editor inside a popup at a angular 6 application.
The feature insertImage should be disabled (not visible).
The Froala div looks like that:

```
<div id="froala-editor" [froalaEditor]="froalaOptions" (froalaInit)="initFroala($event)">Hello, Froala!</div>
```

At the js (typescript) I set (without insertImage):

```
    public initFroala(froala) {
    $('#froala-editor').froalaEditor({
        toolbarButtons: ['fullscreen', 'bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strikeThrough', 'subscript', 'superscript', '|', 
        'fontFamily', 'fontSize', 'color', 'inlineStyle', 'paragraphStyle', '|', 'paragraphFormat', 'align', 
        'formatOL', 'formatUL', 'outdent', 'indent', 'quote', '-', 'insertLink', 'insertVideo', 'insertFile', 'insertTable', '|', 
        'emoticons', 'specialCharacters', 'insertHR', 'selectAll', 'clearFormatting', '|', 'print', 'help', 'html', '|', 'undo', 'redo']
    });
}
```

But the insertImage-Button is still there.
How to enable the insertButton?

Thanks for help.
Frank

Comment: I tried also:    

public froalaOptions: Object = {
        charCounterCount: true,
        height: 300,
        events: {
            'froalaEditor.focus': function(e, editor) {
                $('#froala-editor').froalaEditor({
                    toolbarButtons: ['fullscreen', 'bold', 'italic']
                });
                console.log(
                    'TEST FROALA '
                );
            },
        }
    };


The log is written, but the buttons are not changed.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the list of tool bar buttons in the **froalaOptions** options that you are passing.

In typescript

```
froalaOptions: any = {
       toolbarButtons: [
        'align',
        'color',
        'fullscreen',
        'bold',
        'italic']
}
```

pass this options to **Froala editor**

```
<div id="froala-editor" [froalaEditor]="froalaOptions" (froalaInit)="initFroala($event)">Hello, Froala!</div>
```

So to remove the `insertImage` button you need just **need not add** that into this list of toolbar buttons.